# doubts regarding migration to big data

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, cloudera

I have a few doubts regarding hadoop

1. In one of the videos published by cloudera an instructer told that in hadoop there is HDFS. Every file will be stored as a set of chucks or blocks. Each block will be replicated three times in different machines to minimize the point of failure. Each mapper will process a single hdfs block.

From these logics i perceived that if i have a server having some 100 peta bytes of logs which are not stored in traditional file system unlike hdfs.

Main doubt 1. Now if i  want to analyse  this huge data efficiently using the mapreduce technique then do i have to  transfer the data in a new server running hdfs and having three times the storage of the old server.

2. In one more video which was also published by cloudera..the instructer mentioned clearly that we dont need to migrate the traditional system to a new system, we can use hadoop and map reduce on top of that. This is little contradictry to the statement mentioned in first point.

Main doubt 2: Lets assume that point 2 statement is true. Now how can this be possible. I mean how can we apply hadoop and map reduce on a traditional file system where there is no  replication of blocks or name node ..deamon on each machine.

My main task is to Facilitate fast  analysis of a huge amount of logs which are currently not stored in hdfs. For doing this  will i need a new server or not.

P.S: I need some good tutorial or Books or some articles which could give me in depth knowledge of big data so that i can start working on it. 
So  recomendations are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

[Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop) is just an infrastructure for running a [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) style workload (for "big data" or "analytics" atop a cluster of servers.

You can use HDFS for data sharing across the nodes, then use Hadoop's built in workload management to distribute work to nodes where the data is stored. This is sometimes called "function shipping."

But it's also possible to *not* use HDFS. You can use another network file sharing / distribution mechanism. FTP (file copies), S3 (access from the Amazon Web Services cloud), and a variety of other clustered/distributed file systems are supported by various vendors/platforms. Some of these move the data to the system on which workload is being done ("data shipping").

Which storage strategy is appropriate, efficient, and performant is a big question, and depends greatly on your infrastructure and your MapReduce app's data access patterns. In general, however, analytics jobs are resource hungry, so only small analytics apps tend to run on servers doing other work (the "original systems"). So processing "big data" does tend to suggest new servers--if not ones you buy, ones you rent temporarily from a cloud service like AWS, RackSpace, etc.--and data streaming from replicas/clones of data captured in production ("secondary storage") rather than data still resident on "primary storage."

If you're just starting out with small or modest apps, you might be able to access data in-place, directly from existing systems. But if you've got 100 PB of logs, you're going to want that processed on systems devoted to the task.